# Hi, I am struggling with a sorting problem

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting

The body of the problem is as follows:
Let *n* be a positive integer. Let *v* be an array with *n* positions counting from 1 to *n* and its elements being different numbers from 1 to *n*
Consider *n* being a power of 2(n = 2^m, with m being a positive integer) and array *v* has the property that for any *i* from 1 to *m* and any *j* from 1 to 2^(*m-i*), there is a *k* from 1 to 2^(*m-i*), so that on the positions in *v* from 2^*i* * (*j*-1)+1 to 2^*i* * *j* there are positive integers from 2^*i* * (*k*-1)+1 to 2^*i* * *k*, randomly. Write a program that sorts the array *v* in an ascending order, using for changing the order of the elements in *v* only the operation FLIP(n, v, 2^*i* * (*j*-1)+1, 2^*i* * *j*), with *i* from 1 to *m* and *j* from 1 to 2^(*m-i*), using the property of the array *v*.

The FLIP operation:

```
void FLIP(int v[], int n, int i, int j) {
    while (i < j) {
        int aux = v[i];
        v[i] = v[j];
        v[j] = aux;
        i++;
        j--;
    }
}
```

Example of input:

```
n = 16
v = [14 13 15 16 11 12 9 10 2 1 4 3 8 7 6 5]
```

Output:

```
v = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16]
```

What i found out is that if you group the elements in array *v* as follows:

2 by 2, the resulting groups have 2 consecutive values(14, 13),(15,16)

4 by 4, the resulting groups have 4 consecutive values(14,13,15,16)

2^i by 2^i, the resulting groups have 2^i consecutive values.

So my mind goes to a divide and conquer approach, but i don't know how to implement it.

Comment: I can't really understand the part with the i,j,k. Can you put up the question verbatim or an image. But yeah seems like he's steering you to a Merge Sort type algo.

Comment: @AdamCarboni i tried to translate the question in english as best as i could. The part with i, j and k has to be written down on paper to be understood, but what i got from it is that if you group the numbers 2^i by 2^i, i being an integer from 1 to m, and m being the power of two that equals n, there are 2^i consecutive numbers in those positions. In the example, if you group the numbers 2 by 2, there are 2 consecutive numbers: 14 and 13, 15 and 16 and so on. If you group them 4 by 4, there are 4 consecutive numbers. 8 by 8, 8 consecutive numbers and so on.

Comment: OK, lets talk this through see if we can't get anywhere.

Comment: OK, lets talk this through see if we can't get anywhere, typically i,j,k are lowercase but I'm using uppercase, not many options to format in comments. N is a power of 2, specifically N = 2^M, and for any I in {1..M} and any J in {1..M-I} there exists a K in {1..M-I} ... and here is where I start to struggle ...  such that in V from index 2^I * (J-1)+1 to 2^I * J then it goes haywire again and says from 2^I * (K-1)+1 to 2^I * K there are integers naturally. What about from index index 2^I * (J-1)+1 to 2^I * J, whats there?

Comment: I see your example array, are they ALL like that? You sure?

Comment: @AdamCarboni My idea is that if i use a divide and conquer algorithm it leaves me with two sides every time. Let's say a and b. for example, let's take an array like this:[4 3 1 2]. I go through it once, using FLIP on 2 numbers at a time, leaving me with [3 4 1 2]. After that i use it again on the whole array, leaving me with [2 1 4 3], then i use flip again for each of the 2 groups. Left side would be a, and right side would be b. If the last number in group a  is bigger than the last number in group b, i use FLIP on them. But i don't know how to implement it with the required FLIP operation.

Comment: I got you, I got you, just registered with me.

Comment: @AdamCarboni Yes, they are all like that.

Comment: It's just a really hard way to say that in every 2^i positions there are 2^i consecutive numbers

Comment: Please note that [real questions have answers, not just tips or advice.](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/01/17/real-questions-have-answers/)

Comment: @AdamCarboni i made a mistake in the example, n is supposed to be 16.

Comment: What operator is **  in 2^i * * (j-1) ?

Comment: @Heyji it was a typo, i'm sorry

Comment: Do you assume 2^i * (j-1) +1 = ((2^i) * (j-1)) +1 or (2^(i * (j-1)) + 1 ?

Comment: @Heyji ((2^i) * (j-1)) +1

Comment: Yeah, I'm thinking you made a mistake, the example doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Adam Carboni yeah, i'm sorry, n is supposed to be equal to 16

Comment: Look: 14 13 out of order, 15 16 in order, 11 12 in order, 9 10 in order, 2 1 out, 4 3 out, 8 7 out, 6 5 out. Unless its supposed to be like that.

Comment: @Adam Carboni yes, it's supposed to be like that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think I got it, I think so ... basically a modification of Merge sort, without merging, but instead using the FLIP function that was required to be used. Took me a while, I had an off by one error in there and it took me a minute.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void FLIP(int v[], int n, int i, int j) {
    while (i < j) {
        int aux = v[i];
        v[i] = v[j];
        v[j] = aux;
        i++;
        j--;
    }
}

void run(int v[], int n, int l, int r) {
    if (n < 2) {
        return;
    }
    if (v[l] > v[r - 1]) FLIP(v, n, l, r-1);
    int m = (l + r) / 2;
    run(v, n / 2, l, m);
    run(v, n / 2, m, r);
}


int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int v[] = { 14,13,15,16,11,12,9,10,2,1,4,3,8,7,6,5 };
    run(v, 16, 0, 16);
    for (int& x : v) cout << x << ' ';
    cout << endl;
}
```